# C# Does non empty standarderror indicate error

Tags: c#, psexec, standard-error

I'm trying to execute psexec process and even though the process runs fine the standard error is not empty.  Is this not a good way to check for error by looking at if standarderror is an empty string?

```
string psexcFn = @"c:\pspec\psexec.exe";

ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(psexcFn);
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p);

//If StandardError string not empty, throw exception.
string stderr = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd().Trim();
if (stderr.Length > 0)
{
    throw new Exception("StandardError: " + stderr);
}
```

Comment: Why are you running psexec? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: _""""Typically"""_ you examine the exit code of the program, where _usually_ 0 means "good" and anything else means bad.

Comment: @mjwills because Im running a .bat file on a remote server

Comment: A variety of software outputs secondary logging info into its stderr, freeing up stdout for actual output. The exit code is a more consistent (but not guaranteed) way to check if something completed successfully.

Comment: No, a non-empty stderr stream does not necessarily indicate an error. Error messages usually will be present there, but so too may other diagnostic messages. To detect an actual error condition, look at the process's exit code. See duplicate..

Comment: `Im running a .bat file on a remote server` What does the batch file do?

Comment: @PeterDuniho That does solve my problem but not the same question since Im asking about standarderror specifically.

Comment: @bakalolo we have absolutly no idea what you are asking about. What we know is the question asks " Is this not a good way to check for error by looking at if standarderror is an empty string?" and indeed duplicate shows the right way of checking (which indirectly means the way shown in the question is not the right one)... Please [edit] the question so it is clear what you are asking about (vs. what is written in the question).

Comment: _"Im asking about standarderror specifically"_ -- well, I suppose someone could've posted an answer that simply said "no." But generally, it's more useful to future readers (and to be clear, they are really the only people who matter here) if the question's answer provides useful information, such as what the right way to check for an error condition is. Which the duplicate does (indeed, you yourself admit that the duplicate is really the question you should have asked in the first place, even if it's not exactly what you wrote above).